# How to check if user entered capacity is larger than the current capacity?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm currently working on a project that works with dogs and the current method I'm working on is supposed to let the user change the kennel capacity. The code below is from the kennel constructor class:

```js
public class Kennel {
  private String name;
  private ArrayList < Dog > dogs;
  private int nextFreeLocation;
  private int capacity;

  /**
   * Creates a kennel with a default size 20
   *
   * @param maxNoDogs
   *            The capacity of the kennel
   */
  public Kennel() {
    this(20);
  }

  /**
   * Create a kennel
   *
   * @param maxNoDogs
   *            The capacity of the kennel
   */
  public Kennel(int maxNoDogs) {
    nextFreeLocation = 0; // no Dogs in collection at start
    capacity = maxNoDogs;
    dogs = new ArrayList < Dog > (capacity); // set up default. This can
    // actually be exceeded
    // when using ArrayList but we
    // won't allow that
    // to happen.
  }

  /**
   * This method sets the value for the name attribute. The purpose of the
   * attribute is: The name of the kennel e.g. "DogsRUs"
   *
   * @param theName
   */
  public void setName(String theName) {
    name = theName;
  }

  /**
   * Set the size of the kennel
   *
   * @param capacity
   *            The max dogs we can house
   * @return
   */

  public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    if (this.capacity > capacity) {
      this.capacity = capacity;
    } else
      System.out.println("The capacity you entered is lower than the current capacity");
  }

  /**
   * Maximum capacity of the kennels
   *
   * @return The max size of the kennel
   */
  public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
  }

  /**
   * This method gets the value for the name attribute. The purpose of the
   * attribute is: The name of the Kennel e.g. "DogsRUs"
   *
   * @return String The name of the kennel
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * This method returns the number of dogs in a kennel
   *
   * @return int Current number of dogs in the kennel
   */
  public int getNumOfDogs() {
    return nextFreeLocation;
  }

  /**
   * Enables a user to add a Dog to the Kennel
   *
   * @param theDog
   *            A new dog to home
   */
  public void addDog(Dog theDog) {
    if (nextFreeLocation >= capacity) {
      System.out.println("Sorry kennel is full - cannot add team");
      return;
    }
    // we add in the position indexed by nextFreeLocation
    // This starts at zero
    dogs.add(theDog);

    // now increment index ready for next one
    nextFreeLocation = nextFreeLocation + 1;
  }

  /**
   * Enables a user to delete a Dog from the Kennel.
   *
   * @param theDog
   *            The dog to remove
   */
  public void removeDog(String who) {
    Dog which = null;
    // Search for the dog by name
    for (Dog d: dogs) {
      if (who.equals(d.getName())) {
        which = d;
      }
    }
    if (which != null) {
      dogs.remove(which); // Requires that Dog has an equals method
      System.out.println("removed " + who);
      nextFreeLocation = nextFreeLocation - 1;
    } else
      System.err.println("cannot remove - not in kennel");
  }

  /**
   * @return String showing all the information in the kennel
   */
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder();
    sbr.append("Data in Kennel " + name + " is:");
    for (Dog d: dogs) {
      sbr.append(d.toString() + "\n");
    }
    return sbr.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Returns an array of the dogs in the kennels
   *
   * @return An array of the correct size
   */
  public Dog[] obtainAllDogs() {
    Dog[] result = new Dog[dogs.size()];
    result = dogs.toArray(result);
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Only returns those dogs who like bones
   *
   * @return An array of dogs of the correct size. If no dogs like bones then
   *         returns an empty array (size 0)
   */
  public List < Dog > obtainDogsWhoLikeBones() {
    List < Dog > result = new ArrayList < Dog > (); // changed to List<dog> so can
    // freely add data without
    // intializing to fixed size
    for (Dog d: dogs) {
      if (d.getLikesBones()) {
        result.add(d);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public Dog search(String name) {
    Dog result = null;
    for (Dog d: dogs) {
      if (name.equals(d.getName())) {
        result = d;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

And this method is from the kennel application class:

```js
private void setKennelCapacity() {
 System.out.print("Enter max number of dogs: ");
 int max = scan.nextInt();
 scan.nextLine();
 kennel.setCapacity(max);
 System.out.println(max + " " + kennel.getCapacity());
}
```

The result is that the else statement is run, it always says the number entered is too low. It probably a small mistake but I'm inexperienced, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usercapacity` is a local variable. Each time you call `setCapacity(int)`, the variable `usercapacity` will be initialized to `0` (that variable will always be 0). Instead, create a field variable to store the capacity in

```
class Kernal {
    private int capacity;

    public void setCapacity(int newCapacity) {
        if(newCapacity < capacity) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot enter a value that is lower than the current capacity");
        }

        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

---

Without the `IllegalArgumentException` (using a simple print statement to notify the user), your method would look like this:

```
public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    if (this.capacity < capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    } else
        System.out.println("The capacity you entered is lower than the current capacity");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion vince ,tried your solution and its crashing at the moment, think it's because I've already declared a capacity which I've added to the question

Comment: @Irrossi You should then remove the `int usercapacity`, and replace all uses of it with `capacity`. Show your full class to make sure we're on the same page. Also, by "crash", what do you mean? What happens specifically? Any errors?

Comment: should of done that in the first place, added it now.

Comment: @Irrossi The reason it crashed before was because i threw an `IllegalArgumentException` if an invalid value was passed in. Check out my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the revised code :), however no matter what number I type in the program responds with the else error message.

Comment: Did you try printing out the result of `nextInt()` to make sure it was valid? Try `System.out.println(max + " " + kennel.getCapacity())`, see what the results are

Comment: I just tried it, it prints out the same error message, but also prints out that I entered 8. which is correct and print 5 as the current capacity, so it's returning the correct values just not changing them for some reason.

Comment: @Irrossi So you're getting an exception thrown? You need to post the stacktrace for it. ANYTIME you get an error like that, you should include the stack trace in the question. That's the best way I can help (I need to know what the error is and on what line/method invocation)

Comment: sorry, when I said error message I meant the else statement stating the capacity can't be changed, no program error message appears, but the code seems fine I don't understand why it's not updating the size.

Comment: @Irrossi You should update your code. You still have the method that uses the local variable. My guess is that either you're falling victim to shadowing (the param var and the field var have the same name) or you might have accidentally put the wrong comparison sign. The only way I can tell is if I can see the code you are executing. The problem before was the use of a local variable when it wasn't needed (which was actually interfering). Ima need to see your current code

Comment: Updated the code now, and the variable name don't seem to interfere I just look through everything.

Comment: @Irrossi Change `this.capacity > capacity` to `this.capacity < capacity`. I probably messed that up in my answer; seems as if you had it correct. The only problem before was the local variable. These recent problems are due to my answer not containing the right comparison sign. My bad! Although, walking through the execution step by step, Im sure you could have found that

Comment: Thanks, figured out that changing to sign reset the default capacity value to 20 aswell, so that was another problem, all's good now thanks for the help :)!

Comment: @Irrossi No problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted answer" by clicking the checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows